How do I get the Geoserver username as an attribute value in a Postgresql database?
We use a WFS-T geoserver with a Postresql database attached.
In the geoserver we currently have a layer that can be edited by some users. The username should be automatically entered as an attribute value in the database each time a row is changed.
Does anyone know how to transfer the username from the geoserver to the database?
We have tried to have the usernames entered by the users, but unfortunately this was not successful, so we are now looking for an automated solution.

I think you can use the ${GSUSER,geoserver}
environment variable,
as described here.
